# A long-standing gnome bugs

Tags: gnome

When run emacs on Ubuntu 19.1, it repeatedly report the error

[image]

Check the issue, [Bug 85715 – Closing displays](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715)

it has not been solved.

emacs crash every 3-5 minutes if restart it.

How could I do with the problem?

Comment: Don't run emacs in daemon mode. BTW, gnuserv works fine with emacs built with gtk+. And if you're using it in a terminal anyway, you can also use the `nox` version or `-nw` option.

Comment: it's the same error if not run in daemon. I run daemon con it report the errors repeatedly, so tried daemon. @dobey